# Proper Java inheritance structure

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, static, abstract

I am writing a 2048 game and self-solver in Java. My most important class is a `Board`, which contains the main game functionality. For efficiency reasons, many aspects of the game are encoded in arrays, such as the transformations for each possible row when moved left or right. In a `static` initialization block, I call `static void generateTables()`, which creates the tables once.

Boards with solving capabilities `extend` `Board` and `implement` `Solver`, an interface containing high-level methods `getDirection()` and `getWorstLocation()` which are used by the interface classes to run the solver and to get hints. The main type of solver I am interested in records a list of heuristic values for all possible rows, then runs expectiminimax search using these values. So I have the class:

```
public class HeuristicBoard extends Board implements Solver {

    private static int[] heuristic; // Lookup table

    /* ... methods omitted ... */

    private int heuristic() {...}
    // Calculates a heuristic value for the entire board based
    // on calls to the following method
    // This method's code could change depending on algorithm implementation.
    private static int heuristic(short row) {...}
    // Checks the lookup table for the row provided
    private static void generateHeuristicTable() {...}
    // Generates the lookup table based on calls to the following method
    private static int heuristic(byte[] row) {...}
    // Calculates the heuristic value for a single row.
    // This method's code could change depending on algorithm implementation.
}
```

Now, I would like to test multiple different heuristics, but with the same expectiminimax algorithm. Therefore, the implementations of `int heuristic()` and `static int heuristic(byte[] row)` would change, while the others would remain the same. What is the best way to abstract the functionality of the `HeuristicBoard` class so as to have multiple child(?) classes that implement `int heuristic()` and `static int heuristic(byte[] row)`? Preferably they would have a common ancestor so I could have:

```
ClassOrInterface firstSolver = new EmptySpaceHeuristicBoard();
ClassOrInterface secondSolver = new MonotonicityHeuristicBoard();
```

What I have thought of and have seen suggested on various StackOverflow answers:

1. Make `HeuristicBoard` `abstract` and make the two methods `abstract`. But for some reason (yes, I have read why) you can't have a `static abstract` method. If I make `static int heuristic(byte[] row)` non-static, I would have no way to use it in the `static void generateHeuristicTable()` method, which should be implemented in the `HeuristicBoard` class, not in a subclass (I would have to re-implement it in each subclass, changing only the throwaway `new SubclassOfHeuristicBoard().heuristic(currentRow)` every time. If I make this method non-static too, ignoring the inconvenience demonstrated above, then I would not be able to call `generateHeuristicTable()` in a `static` initialization block, thus making it so that the (large) table would be generated with every new instance of the class.
2. Make a `HeuristicSolver` interface which includes the static method, then have `HeuristicBoard` `implement` `HeuristicSolver`, then subclass `HeuristicBoard`. However, this forces me to provide a default implementation of the static method, which I don't think makes sense. Only the subclasses ought to be instantiated, because only they ought to provide a heuristic implementation. Furthermore, the other static methods in the class reference static variables only found in the `Board` class.
3. There are other possibilities, but they really just get worse after making `HeuristicBoard` non-abstract.

It seems to me that the only proper way to do this is to make `HeuristicBoard` `abstract`, but I can't figure out what to do with the `static` method.

EDIT: It has been pointed out that both methods can be changed to be `non-static`. This solves the above problems, but now I have another problem: in the non-static AI method, I duplicate the board for recursive purposes: `HeuristicBoard option = new HeuristicBoard(board)`. If the class is abstract, however, I can't do this. How should I create an instance of whichever the current class is? (i.e. in the `EmptySpaceHeuristicBoard` class, when this method is inherited and executed, it should create a `new EmptySpaceHeuristicBoard()`.

Comment: For starters, I think it's a bad design to use the static initializer.  Just check and see if the table is `null` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. A static method can always be implemented as an instance method that doesn't use any instance variables, so that should solve your problem with not being able to override the static method.
2. I don't understand why heuristic board is extending board. I think it makes more sense to have a Solver class with a method like `scoreBoard()`  that takes a board.
3. 2048 is not an minimax game, because the 'opponent' doesn't choose the 'min' option,  but rather a random option. Therefore the optimizer to use is expectimax.

Comment: I use expectimax to find the best possible move, and minimax to find the worst possible tile placement, depending on mode. I stated the optimizer misleadingly, oops.

Comment: Also: isn't it bad practice to make a static method into an instance method with no instance variables? Doesn't that defeat the entire purpose of a static method?

Comment: Being able to override the method is a good reason to not make it static.